# Need Domain Name assistance - Please

Tags: dns

I have a small issue. I have tried for the last hour to find a solution for this on this and many other websites. I have found similar but none have provided an answer that works. Heres that problem:

I have a badge on my website that was given to me by Norton online protection. they provided me with a script file and I placed it where it should go. NOW, this script is registered to **"www.example.com"** but if someone goes to their browsertypes in just **"example.com"** without the WWW. the Norton badge never shows.

I spoke with Godaddy this morning and they have no solution so that's why I'm asking on here.

Is there a to send a domiain name to the same domain name? so that it always shows the WWW?

Comment: I suspect the script (and the validation that goes with it) is *per-domain*, in that you'll need to purchase/license `example.com` separately. Without more information, there's simply no way to know for sure though.

Comment: is there a way with code to tell the site if someone lands on "example.com" go to "www.example.com"?

Comment: Yes; you can probably google that phrase and you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your webserver such that www.example.com is one site (your actual site with your content), and you have another site that is example.com (no www subdomain) as a site that you can now configure to redirect to your actual site. How that step is done depends on which webserver you are using, but basically these is a way to do that on any webserver (Apache, IIS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read the URL and check if 'www' is present in the URL. If it is not present redirect the visitors to www.example.com

In php you could use the below for redirection

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```